# Map multiple properties to the single column in Hibernate (UserType seems to be insufficient)

Tags: java, hibernate, mapping, usertype

we have a lot of tables with the columns defined the following way:

```
create table tbl_1 (
id int primary key,
   -- ... a lot of specific stuff skipped
reserved_1 char (10), -- byte 1:   flag_A
                      -- byte 2-5: value_B
                      -- byte 6:   flag_C
                      -- byte 7-8: value_D
                      -- byte 9-10: not used 
                      --   flag_A, value_B, flag_C, value_D
                      --   have no relations to each other in general
reserved_2 char(10),  -- ....
);
```

I'd like to map it to the class like following:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TBL_1", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "ID"))
public class Tbl1 implements java.io.Serializable {
    private int id;
//  irrelevant properties skipped
    private String flagA;
    private String valueB;
    private String flagC;
    private String valueD;
// getters/setters will follow
}
```

Is it possible in Hibernate?  As far as I understood, it's possible
to combine them into single column with UserType like the following (simplified):

```
public class Tbl1 implements java.io.Serializable {
   private int id;
//  irrelevant properties skipped
   private Reserved1 reserved1;
}

public class Reserved1 implements java.io.Serializable {
    private String flagA;
    private String valueB;
    private String flagC;
    private String valueD;
}
```

but I'd like to hide all the references to reserved1 column/property at all
and to advertise getters/setters for flagA, valueB, flagC, valueD only, as they are
unrelated to each other, so combining then to the class is a bad idea,  and to 
keep the flexibility for future (hopefully) table reorganizations. Is it possible
in Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

OK, actually it's easy: just define custom queries for fetch, update and insert:

```
@SQLUpdate (sql = "UPDATE tbl_1 SET oth_col=?, reserved_1=(substring(?||' ' from 1 for 1) || substring(?||'    ' from 1 for 4) || substring(?||' ' from 1 for 1) || substring(?||'  ' from 1 for 2) where id=?")
@SQLInsert (sql = "define it the same way as update")
@Loader (namedQuery = "tbl_1_ldr")
@NamedNativeQuery (name="tbl_1_ldr", query="SELECT id,..., substring(reserved_1 from 1 for 1) as flag_a, substring(reserved_1 from 2 for 4) as value_b, substring(reserved_1 from 6 for 1) as flag_c, substring(reserved_1 from 7 for 2) as value_d FROM tbl_1 WHERE id = ? ")
```